# Rule is not changing field value

Tags: nodes, rules, ubercart

I am new to Drupal.

I have created a rule on specific event, and changing the value of `node:field-seat-limit`

#### Event

- After updating an existing order product

#### Conditions

- Content is of type event
- `uc-order-product:node:field-seat-limit` (negate)

#### Action

- Decrement uc-order-product:node:field-seat-limit by using `$value= $value-1;`

Result: I am displaying field-seat-limit in a view, where it is showing the decremented count but when I go to the node, it shows the count that I entered first time.

What is causing the node to fail to reflect the updated value?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail? What is the event, and what value are you changing? How can you tell that it's changing the value of the field, and what should it look like on the node?

Comment: Yes,
My event is: After updating an existing order product


Condition: 
1. Content is of type event
2. uc-order-product:node:field-seat-limit (negate)


Action: 
1. Decrement uc-order-product:node:field-seat-limit
by using $value= $value-1;

Result:
I am displaying field-seat-limit in view, it is showing decremented count but when i am going to node, it is showing count that i entered first time.

Thanks For Response

IF u want more detail information please tell.

Comment: That helps a lot. I added it to the question so it will be easier for others to follow your steps.

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm also curious which version of Drupal and Ubercart you're using?

Comment: Export Rules and show in drupalbin...

Comment: I am using Drupal 7, thanks beth for editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to save the changes after you make them.  After your decrement action, add another action to save the entity.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is indeed ***the*** solution ...